# Run migrations without loading initial_data.json

Tags: django, django-migrations, django-fixtures

I provide a lista of users for my application in a json located in my app:

```
myapp/
  fixtures/
    initial_data.json
```

it load everytime I run `python manage.py migrate`. I've read the [Providing initial data for models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/initial-data/#automatically-loading-initial-data-fixtures) document, but it does not mention anything about avoid loading it.

I wonder if there's a command to run `python manage.py migrate` without load initial_data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider upgrade to Django==1.8. You shouldn't have many problems after upgrade. What's your Django version?

Anyway, take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/initial-data/#automatically-loading-initial-data-fixtures), since Django>=1.7 automatic loading of fixtures doesn't work:

> If an application uses migrations, there is no automatic loading of fixtures

An application uses migrations when you have the **migrations** folder with the **__init__.py** file inside it.

If you use Django>=1.7 and you use migrations in your app, you don't have automatic fixtures loading when you run `python manage.py migrate`.

But, if you don't use migrations in your app, you always have automatic  fixtures loading if your fixture file is named *initial_data.json*.

You can rename the **initial_data.json** file to any other name (like mydata.json) in order to avoid automatic fixtures loading, then, you can load the data any time you want by running:

`django-admin.py loaddata mydata.json`

Comment: I'm using Django 1.8.3 and when I run migrate initial_data loads, I want to avoid it sometimes.

Comment: Are you sure the fixtures are loaded every time you migrate? Let me see your migrations files. Have you edit them?

Comment: No, I haven't. I just created an app and put a folder named "fixtures" inside and add a initial_data.json file. Now when I run python manage.py migrate, initial_data file data is loaded in db

Comment: Create a folder named **migrations** between *fixtures* folder, put a file named **__init__.py**  inside it. Then, run:
`python manage.py makemigrations`
and
`python manage.py migrate`.

Any time you can view the migrations on your project runing:

`python manage.py migrate --list`

Comment: Provided data are loading, and that is fine. But I recently made a change in a model and migrations fails, because the data in json haven't those new fields, that's why I wonder if there's a command to avoid loading initial_data

Comment: You can temporarily rename the folder *fixtures* or the *initial_data* file, if there aren't fixtures to load, the migrate command won't load any fixtures. 

PD: do you have the migrations folder?

Comment: Yes, I have a migrations folder. That's what I did, I needed run the project fast so I didn't any search and I just renamed the folder and ran migrate command, but after that I wonder if it is possible to avoid loading initial data with a command, change the folder's name is not elegant I think.

Comment: The answer is not, you can not prevent to load initial data when run migrations if your file is named *initial_data.json*, and of course, rename the folder is not elegant, but rename initial_data.json is a good idea, when you need to load the fixtures you should run `django-admin.py loaddata mydata.json`.

You need to fix your migrations files in order to avoid problems. How many migrations files do you have? what shows the `python manage.py migrate --list` command?

Comment: I have 11 files in migrations folder. and `python manage.py migrate --list` shows the list of files.

Comment: What do you think about renaming *initial_data* file?

Comment: Yes, looks like that's the best option, rename it and load explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You should use data migration instead, because fixtures are not for use together with migrations. Fixtures are deprecated since Django 1.7 and will be removed in Django 1.9

Comment: Thanks for your answer. [Providing initial SQL data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-sql-data) is deprecated and will be removed. Django's documentation for version 1.8 still recomend to use .json format

Comment: .json format is not deprecated, loading initial data fixtures this way is. Move your fixture to migrations folder and create migration that will push data from fixture into database.